# How does hash functions (such as md5) verify if the files downloaded are not corrupt?

Tags: file, hash

I wish to know how do software verify the downloaded files are not corrupt by using hash functions?

Comment: do you understand how password hashing works?

Comment: I know basics of what hash function does but what I want to know is how this is implemented to check if the file downloaded isn't corrupt.

Comment: @MichaelColeman just to encode the password in some way that if someone gets access to your database, they won't get the actual passwords because they don't have the decoder?

Comment: why I asked was If @yask understands the process of password encryption, is because if they do, then they will pretty easily make the jump to being able to understand how hashing is used for verifying a file or text string

Comment: @Michael Yes , I do understand how hashing works.

Comment: If you put downloaded file data into the hash function and that data is the same as the file provider hashed, then you should get the exact same hash value they did.  If even a single bit has been changed, or the file is longer or shorter, a good N-bit hash will have close to 1 in 2^N chance of incorrectly telling you the file data matches.  Hash sizes from 32 to 256+ bits are common enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_verification,

"Hash-based verification ensures that a file has not been corrupted by comparing the file's hash value to a previously calculated value. If these values match, the file is presumed to be unmodified." That's how

Comment: what do you mean by ' file's hash value `?
what data of file is being hashed?

Comment: from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn520872.aspx, - "A hash value is a unique value that corresponds to the content of the file."

Answer (score 1):

Consider password hash verfication process....
you signup to "www.example.com" and they ask for your password

"your-secret-password" >> gets hashed and becomes `gn234hs` (for example)
You now have a "reference" hash

you come back a month later and as long as you provide same password the hash function will produce the same output `gn234hs` - which matches the original and verifies that what you entered is the same as what was entered last time.

No big insights there....

what if, instead of feeding in a password - someone feed a binary representation of a file or a collection of text files into the hashing function.

[010101001010101... **huge number**] >> hash function
hash function produces `32j4h234j234k23j4h23k4h23kj423kj4h3`
you now have a "reference hash" for that file.

Now you get a file off the internet

If you run the file through the same hashing function and you get 
`32j4h234j234k23j4h23k4h23kj423kj4h3` - same as for a  password - you know the file is a bit for bit representation of the original.

So the question is, I get how a hash can represent a password thats only a few characters , but how can a hash represent an unbelievably huge binary sequence or text file, be "sensitive" enough to detect changes and still have a unique quality?
Basically, because of the "randomness" of the output of cryptographic hash functions (as distinct from ordinary hashes) and the number of possible combinations a hash can have is so huge, that whilst its possible for different permutations of the items being hashed to result in the same hash - its so small as to be considered statistically insignificant.

Its a bit oversimplified, but hopefully that helps.
There (obviously) is tons of info on the subject if you google it, e.g. the wiki article linked to already.